# FMDB doesn't output to UTF-8 encoding

Tags: objective-c, utf-8, sqlite, fmdb

I'm new to FMDB and I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/836_Persisting_iOS_Application_Data_in_SQLite_Database_Using_FMDB.aspx). I create the database in terminal. I'm having a problem after I add my database to xcode and compile. It is not automatically in UTF-8. There are weird characters so there are lots of errors and it won't compile. Here's a screenshot: [image: You can see all the weird characters.]

Comment: So you've added the `.sqlite` file as a file to compile?  Hmmm, where to start...

Comment: I add it as customers.db.

Comment: Well you only compile source files don't you, so you need to add it as a resource so it will be copied into the app bundle during the build.  However if you want to update it (you probably will) then it needs to be copied from the app bundle into the app's document folder at runtime.  There are examples of this around, I'm sure.

Comment: I add Customers.db under supporting files and then change the type to Objective-C Source and I try to change the text encoding to utf-8 but that doesn't work.

Comment: Why do you change the database file's type to Objective-C (it isn't) and the encoding (it's not a text file, it's binary)? The tutorial did not tell you to do that.

Comment: @CL. thank you so much! Do you want to put it as the answer and I'll mark it as accurate?

Comment: I don't know XCode; I can see that those settings were wrong, but I cannot write what would be correct. You'll have to write the answer yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite is a binary format, and as such, you won't be able to view it or compile it in Xcode.  Instead, you want to make sure it is treated as a resource like images.  Make sure it's copied to your resources folder as well.

FMDB + SQLite does UTF-8 just fine- but the Xcode editor isn't the way to view it (you'll have to get at its contents pragmatically).

Comment: I am so honored that you are the one who answered! The guy who responded in the comments explained what I was doing wrong.

Comment: Another question, Gus, can I add to the database in the first view controller and then see it in another?